# How can I iterate over a sequence multiple times within a function?

Tags: rust

I have a function that I would like to take an argument that can be looped over. However I would like to loop over it twice. I tried using the `Iterator` trait however I can only iterate over it once because it consumes the struct when iterating.

How should I make it so my function can loop twice? I know I could use `values: Vec<usize>` however I would like to make it generic over any object that is iterable.

Here's an [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8a03fccb54247d8a5e73c52ba423e3e1) of what I would like to do: (Please ignore what the loops are actually doing. In my real code I can't condense the two loops into one.)

```
fn perform<'a, I>(values: I) -> usize
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a usize>,
{
    // Loop one: This works.
    let sum = values.sum::<usize>();

    // Loop two: This doesn't work due to `error[E0382]: use of moved value: 
    // `values``.
    let max = values.max().unwrap();
    sum * max
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let result = perform(v.iter());
    print!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

Comment: Use `I: Iterator<Item = &á usize> + Clone` instead, then clone the iterator before starting

Comment: The solution by @mousetail works - thanks. Shall I write it up as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate over the same iterator twice, because iterators are not guaranteed to be randomly accessible. For example, [`std::iter::from_fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.from_fn.html) produces an iterator that is most definitely not randomly accessible.

As @mousetail already mentioned, one way to get around this problem is to expect a `Clone`able iterator:

```
fn perform<'a, I>(values: I) -> usize
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a usize> + Clone,
{
    // Loop one: This works.
    let sum = values.clone().sum::<usize>();

    // Loop two: This doesn't work due to `error[E0382]: use of moved value:
    // `values``.
    let max = values.max().unwrap();
    sum * max
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let result = perform(v.iter());
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

```
Result: 40
```

Although in your specific example, I'd compute both `sum` and `max` in the same iteration:

```
fn perform<'a, I>(values: I) -> usize
where
    I: Iterator<Item = &'a usize>,
{
    let (sum, max) = values.fold((0, usize::MIN), |(sum, max), &el| {
        (sum + el, usize::max(max, el))
    });

    sum * max
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    let result = perform(v.iter());
    println!("Result: {}", result);
}
```

```
Result: 40
```